# Invalid input ')': expected whitespace or a variable Creating INDEX

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create BTREE index as follows:

```
CREATE BTREE INDEX index_r_connected FOR  ()-[r:connected_to]->() on (r.source,r.target)
```

But I am getting following error :

> ```
> > Invalid input 'I': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels,
> > MapLiteral, a parameter, a parameter (old syntax), a relationship
> > pattern, ',', FROM GRAPH, USE GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START,
> > MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE,
> > FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1,
> > column 14 (offset: 13)) "CREATE BTREE INDEX index_r_connected FOR 
> > ()-[r:connected_to]->() on (r.source,r.target)"
> ```

Comment: That syntax works for me on 4.3.3 Enterprise Edition. I think it should be available on community edition too. What version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: Does the user have the `CREATE INDEX` privilege ? Do you even have authentication enabled? I have seen this error when we had auth disabled

Comment: I am able to create index in following format "CREATE INDEX ON :NODE(NAME)", I am using community edition (4.3.6)